# modifying remote branch without local - what are the consequences?

Tags: git, git-branch

Git [manual states](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) that remote branches can't be modified

> Remote branches are references (pointers) to the state of branches in
>   your remote repositories. They’re local branches that you can’t move;
>   they’re moved automatically for you whenever you do any network
>   communication.

But I've just discovered that I actually can do that.
Here is the experiment:

```
 cd rep1 && git init
 echo "remote" > f1.txt
 git add f1.txt
 git commit -m "remote 1st commit"
 git checkout -b new // switch branch to allow push to master from another repository
```

So this commit's hash is `81d86e051a9c85347f3faab16e5b50d96093b75d`.
Now I want to have the branch as remote in another repository called `rep2`:

```
 cd rep2 && git init
 git remote add origin "../rep1"
 git fetch origin master
 git branch -a //outputs remotes/origin/master
 git checkout origin/master
```

So now I've checked out the remote branch but HEAD is in detached state. I then change `f1.txt` and commit changes:

```
echo "local change" > f1.txt && git add f1.txt
git commit -m "local commit 2"
```

The HEAD is now pointing to my new commit's hash `9ae81a259749351186f7d9f27269f1068fcafc80`, but the `origin/master` still points to the commit `81d86e051a9c85347f3faab16e5b50d96093b75d` made on `rep1`.
And now the magic:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Which updates both master branch pointers both on remote `rep1`:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
81d86e051a9c85347f3faab16e5b50d96093b75d        HEAD
9ae81a259749351186f7d9f27269f1068fcafc80        refs/heads/master
```

And local `rep2`:

```
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
9ae81a259749351186f7d9f27269f1068fcafc80
```

Hence I've updated remote branch without ever creating local branch. The interesting fact here is that `HEAD` hasn't changed on remote, although I don't know yet what to make of it.

So why have I spent 30 minutes experimenting and typing it? If possible, I'd like to know the issues that will likely occur because of such approach.

PS. Disclaimer, I'm definitely not going to use this approach, it's just curiosity.

Comment: *Git manual states that remote branches can't be modified [...]*. Could you edit your question to add a reference to the manual? It would be nice to read the quote in context. For what it's worth, `git push origin HEAD:master` is a perfectly valid command, but why would you expect it to move `HEAD` in rep1? After you've run `git checkout -b new`, `HEAD` points at branch `new` in that repository; there is no reason why pushing anything (from rep2) to `origin/master` should move rep1's `HEAD`.

Comment: You write *`git branch -b new`*. Surely, you mean `git checkout -b new` (the `branch` verb doesn't have any `-b` flag).

Comment: Added reference to the manual. No, I don't expect `git push` to move `HEAD`, it was just an observation. The interesting thing is that it's actually possible to move remote branch pointers locally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *locally*. I think you're getting confused because everything in your example happens locally: rep1, which acts as a remote for rep2, is on the same machine as rep2. However, *pushing* from one remote to  another is, in general, not a strictly local operation. The fact that you're doing this locally in your example is only incidental.

Comment: By `locally` I mean `from rep2` which has `rep1` as its remote.

Comment: What I am saying is that the only way you can change the state of a repo that isn't the one you're in is through pushing, which is what you're doing here. Pushing is not a local operation.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I'm just curios of the consequences of such approach to working with remote branches (updating them without creating local)

Comment: Also, as I understand, `git push` updates references in `refs/remotes` after updating them on the repository where commits where pushed, correct?

Comment: This is turning into a discussion. Please refactor your question: clarify it and mention everything that puzzles you there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> they’re moved automatically for you whenever you do any network communication.

That is exactly what you did, a network operation:

```
 git push origin HEAD:master
```

That instructed the remote repo `rep1` `master` branch to fetch+merge the current `rep2` commit HEAD.

> `git push` updates references in `refs/remotes` after updating them on the repository where commits where pushed, correct?

Yes, the remote tracking branch `remotes/origin/master` in local `rep2` is therefore updated to remember the fact that the remote `master` (in `rep1`) now reference that new commit (since the push was done on `rep1` as a fast-forward merge).